# When opening image with PILLOW the image is modified

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When opening the postscript image with online tools all the pixels align correctly but when using pillow, the pixels are in different sizes.

[Image of the problem]
[image: 1]

[Image of the desired result]
[image: 2]

```
def saveFile(canvas:tk.Canvas):

    EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary = r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c'

    file_name = "img"

    canvas.postscript(file=f"images\ps\{file_name}.ps", colormode='color')

    psimage=Image.open(f'images\ps\{file_name}.ps')
    psimage.save(f'images\png\{file_name}.png', "png")
    psimage.close()
```

Keep in mind the pixels are not the size of a 'real' pixel, they are much bigger and changing the format to 'png' or 'jpg' didn't solve the problem.

If someone knows the solution to this problem, I will greatly appreciate it.

Sorry for the missing information, hopefully this is enough.

[Img.ps file as text](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1j1j74pec8MSZKRu16e2hrARRen4cpDDW)

And this is how the code generates the .ps file

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random
from save import saveFile


pixels = []

FIELD_SIZE = (1280, 720)
PIXEL_SIZE = 10

class random_pixels():

    def draw_full_screen(canvas):
        height = round(FIELD_SIZE[1] / PIXEL_SIZE)
        width = round(FIELD_SIZE[0] / PIXEL_SIZE)
        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                color = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('ABCDEF0123456789') for i in range(6)])]
                # color = "#444"

                x_top_left = x * PIXEL_SIZE + 1
                y_top_left = y * PIXEL_SIZE + 1
                x_bottom_right = x_top_left + PIXEL_SIZE - 1
                y_bottom_right = y_top_left + PIXEL_SIZE - 1 
                resolution = width * height

                util.draw_pixel(canvas, color, x_top_left, x_bottom_right, y_top_left, y_bottom_right, resolution)

                canvas.update()
        canvas.update()

        print("\nPixels drawn!")
        print("\nSaving image...")

        saveFile(canvas) 

        canvas.focus_set()

        print('\nImage saved!')

class util:
    def draw_pixel(canvas:tk.Canvas, color, x0, x, y0, y, pixels_to_draw=1):

            pixel = canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x, y, fill=color, outline=color)

            pixels.append(pixel)

            print(f"{len(pixels)}/{pixels_to_draw} | { round(len(pixels) / pixels_to_draw * 100, 2)}%")

            return None

    def get_theme(e, canvas, root):

        if len(pixels) != 0:
            canvas.delete('all')
            pixels.clear()

        root.focus_set()

        if e.char == "g":
            random_pixels.draw_full_screen(canvas)
        canvas.focus_set()
```

Comment: Pixels in a PostScript file do not have an inherent "size".  I don't know what size canvas PIL is assuming, but it's certainly going to fill that canvas.  Also remember PIL is relying on GhostScript to do the PostScript interpretation.  Does this look OK if you have GhostScript do the conversion directly?

Comment: When I meant pixels it was more like squares of a size around 10 by 10 pixels and the size of the squares is what gets modified to, for example 10 by 8 pixels, and i don't undestand what you mean by doing the convesion directly with ghostscript

Comment: Please either a) give **complete** code to create a suitable, simple postscript file that causes PIL problems, or b) share one you have created - using Dropbox or Google Drive or similar. Thank you.

Comment: Postscript does not measure things in "pixels".  Postscript uses real world units -- by default, points.  It's up to whatever is doing the rendering (app or printer) to decide how to map points to pixels.  Can you put the ps file somewhere we can read it?  How did you create it?

Comment: When I run your code on your file, the resulting png is 961x542.  That the same size I get if I use ImageMagick to convert the .ps to .pdf.  What size are you getting?  Tk is such a terrible tool; can't you just use PIL from the beginning?

Comment: I followed your advice on using PIL and now everything works fine, thanks for the help.